# A Particular Wavy Brick Pattern

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]

[image]

I'm hoping to create something like this procedurally, but I'm not sure where to start. It's a brick texture with a color that repeats in a wavy fashion. I know I should use modulo somehow, but I'm not sure? Could a node wizard help out?

Comment: do you have a single mesh? why don't you use a mesh and an array modifier?

Comment: I guess that's true. I was thinking on the shading level but that makes sense